# Links to Hostelbookers are not allowed?

Tags: discussion, support

I tried editing [an answer on a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18130/not-booking-hostels-in-europe-this-summer) which had linked to hostelworld but had no link to hostelbookers. For some reason, links to hostelbookers are not allowed - I get an error??

As someone who has had multiple hostel owners relate how they feel hostelworld is the evil one and hostelbookers is the 'nice' one, I'm very curious as to a reason why this URL is banned?

**It's not a spam site, it's a very useful site, and highly relevant for travel.SE.**

Comment: Works for me. Can you post the exact URL you are trying to linkify?

Comment: Stupid site. Works just fine now. Perhaps there was just a SE network problem with adding links at the time :/

Comment: BTW, [Hostelbookers was acquired by Hostelworld](http://www.tnooz.com/2013/04/11/news/massive-consolidation-hostelworld-buys-hostelbookers/) so one of them being 'nice' / 'evil' is moot now. :p

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee yeah, I'm hoping (naive?) that they'll still let them run themselves as they were, rather than trying to impose their own rules on them :/